# Can't boot Ubuntu 12.10 from ISO and get "NTLDR is Missing" when booting from HD

Tags: boot, 12.10, iso

I can't seem to load Ubuntu 12.10 onto my new system.  It uses the ASRock pro4-M motherboard and an Ivybridge Core I3 processor.

With no hard drive initially connected, the computer won't boot from the ISO image.  When I connect a reformatted (formerly XP) hard drive, I get "NTLDR is Missing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just to rule out one possibility, did you use a proper CD burning software (Brasero, Nero, Roxio, Deepburner) and set it to burn a bootable ISO? (As opposed to a standard data CD.) I only ask because it's a common mistake among newer users.
2. Did you change the boot order in your BIOS? F2, F10, & Esc are common keys to get to the BIOS Setup &/or Boot menu.
3. I'm not aware of any compatibility issues with that hardware.

Comment: Users also need to check the md5sum of the downloaded iso: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM . The DVD should then be burnt as a bootable disk at the slowest possible speed for the best chance of a reliable burn.  It does seem like Richard has copied the iso to a data disk however: "boot from the iso image" is not a trivial exercise for the uninitiated and requires the installation of a separate boot loader - much easer to burn the iso as a bootable disk and use that instead.

Comment: Also, in reference to the ntldr issue, I've detailed a fix on ubuntuforums. Just follow the link, then follow the directions. You will need to create an account in order to download the file.  
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1603143&highlight=ntldr  

Tomorrow, when I'm on an actual PC, I 'll clean this up a bit by putting the actual directions here and then providing a link.

Comment: Thanks, I used the right burner but I burned it as data instead of write ISO under tools in the program.  When I burned it the right way it all worked out.